# Manipulating first character of each line in a file with .Replace()

Tags: powershell

Say I have a text file `123.txt`

```
one,two,three
four,five,six
```

My goal is to capitalize the first character of each line by using `Get-Culture`. This is my attempt:

```
$str = gc C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\123.txt

#Split each line into an array
$array = $str.split("`n")

for($i=0; $i -lt $array.Count; $i++) {
    #Returns O and F:
    $text = (Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($array[$i].Substring(0,1))

    #Supposed to replace the first letter of each array with $text
    $array[$i].Replace($array[$i].Substring(0,1), $text) >> .\Desktop\finish.txt
}
```

Result:

`One,twO,three
Four,Five,six`

I understand that `.Replace()` is replaces every occurrence of the current array, which is why I made sure that it's replacing ONLY the first character of the array with `$array[$i].Substring(0,1)`, but this doesn't work.

Comment: `$text + $array[$i].substring(1) >> .\Desktop\finish.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Get-Content C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\123.txt | ForEach-Object {
  if ($_) {
    $_.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + $_.Substring(1)
  } else {
    $_
  }
} > .\Desktop\finish.txt
```

- `Get-Content` reads the input file line by line and sends each line - stripped of its line terminator - through the pipeline.
- `ForEach-Object` processes each line in the associated script block, in which `$_` represents the line at hand:

  - `if ($_)` tests if the line is nonempty, i.e. if there's at least 1 character; if not, the `else` block simply passes the empty line through.
  - `$_.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper()` converts the line's 1st character to uppercase, implicitly using the current culture (with a single character, this is equivalent to applying `Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase()`).
  - `+ $_.Substring(1)` appends the rest of the line.
- Only `>` rater than `>>` is needed to write to the output file, because the entire pipeline's output is written at once.

Answer (score 2):

The reason this is not working is because you are replacing the character...

```
$array[$i].Substring(0,1)
```

... but you are using the Replace method on the entire array element

```
$array[$i].Replace(...
```

Here the array element is a string, equal to a line of the input. So it will replace every occurrence of that character.

`Get-Content` (unless you use the `-Raw` parameter) by default returns the text as an array of strings. So you should be able to use this regex replace (I have used `ToString().ToUpper()` - nothing wrong with the `Get-Culture` method)

```
$str = gc C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\123.txt

foreach($line in $str){
    $line -replace '^\w', $line[0].ToString().ToUpper() >> .\Desktop\finish.txt
}
```

**Regex explanation:**
`^` is an anchor. It specifies "the beginning of the string"
`\w` matches a word character - usually a-z, A-Z, 0-9
<sub>See mklement0's comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49309752/manipulating-first-character-of-each-line-in-a-file-with-replace/49309933?noredirect=1#comment85622343_49309933) for the more focused `^\p{Ll}` and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49309752/manipulating-first-character-of-each-line-in-a-file-with-replace/49309933?noredirect=1#comment85622606_49309933)  for further explanation</sub>

Comment: If my understanding of this is correct, `-replace` would attempt to replace every character in the string, but only completes the replacement if it is an actual letter or number?

Comment: @PotatoUser `'^\w'` means "at the start of the string (^) look for word characters (letters and numbers not whitespace), and only one of them because there's no repetition code in there. So it only replaces the first character of each string.

Comment: @PotatoUser: `-replace`  in principle replaces _all_ matches it finds, but in this case, because the regex is anchored at the start of the input (`^`) it matches only _once_, namely if the first character is a word character (`\w`); you could make this more focused with `^\p{Ll}`, which would only match a (Unicode) lowercase letter.

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks - edited as that part wasn't clear. And for the additional info on `\w` - didn't know that.

Comment: @gms0ulman: Thanks for updating; I deleted the `\w` info along with my previous comment, so here it is again, in more complete form: .NET regexes are Unicode aware, so a word character (`\w`) is not just `_`, `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` in the _ASCII_ range - which would imply only English letters and digits - but encompasses _all_ letters, and _all_ digits; e.g. `'ü' -match '\w'` is `$True` too, and so is `'᠓' -match '\w'`, where `᠓` is the `MONGOLIAN DIGIT THREE` character (`U+18131`).